# Поменять местами слова в ячейке

Tags: excel

Вот пример одной ячейки из файла в excel:
`Avatyre Freeze 175/65/14 82Q`.
Нужна формула, что бы поменять местами слова, что бы получилось:
`175/65/14 82Q Avatyre Freeze`
, именно формула, так как я далеко не программист, и макросами не владею(
желательно с пояснениями)
заранее спасибо)

Comment: Слова разной или фиксированной длины? приведите пример нескольких значений.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Разделение по первому числовому символу:

```
=ПСТР(A1;МИН(ПОИСК({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0};A1&1234567890))+1;50)&" "&ЛЕВБ(A1;МИН(ПОИСК({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0};A1&1234567890))-1)
```

Разделение по первому пробелу:

```
=ПСТР(A1&" "&A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1)+1;ДЛСТР(A1))
```

Поиск "/" при 3-значном первом числе:

```
=ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК("/";A1)-3;50)&" "&ЛЕВБ(A1;ПОИСК("/";A1)-4)
```

50 в формулах - число не меньше длины второй части текста.

При фиксированной длине фрагментов:

```
=ПРАВБ(A1;13)&" "&ЛЕВБ(A1;15)
```

Вариантов может быть много, зависит от данных.